# imageMagick doesn't compile with cpp

Tags: c++, imagemagick

I have  tried to install imagemagick but had some issues. Firstly, i have tried to run tutorial, but have noticed that lib was installed to ImageMagic-7 directory so i did this `saprykin@work:/usr/local/include/ImageMagick-7$ sudo cp -r * ../`. But when i try to compile i receive this error

```
saprykin@work:~/image_proc$ c++ `Magick++-config --cxxflags --cppflags` -O2 -o main src/main.cpp   `Magick++-config --ldflags --libs`
/usr/local/bin/Magick++-config: 47: --cflags: not found
/usr/local/bin/Magick++-config: 50: --cflags: not found
/usr/local/bin/Magick++-config: 53: --libs: not found
/usr/local/bin/Magick++-config: 56: --libs: not found
In file included from /usr/local/include/Magick++/Include.h:16,
                 from /usr/local/include/Magick++.h:12,
                 from src/main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/MagickCore/magick-config.h:63:3: warning: #warning "you should set MAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH to sensible default set it to configure time default" [-Wcpp]
   63 | # warning "you should set MAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH to sensible default set it to configure time default"
      |   ^~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/MagickCore/magick-config.h:64:3: warning: #warning "this is an obsolete behavior please fix your makefile" [-Wcpp]
   64 | # warning "this is an obsolete behavior please fix your makefile"
      |   ^~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/MagickCore/magick-config.h:86:3: error: #error "you should set MAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE"
   86 | # error "you should set MAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE"
      |   ^~~~~
/usr/local/include/MagickCore/magick-config.h:121:3: error: #error "you should set MAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE"
  121 | # error "you should set MAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE"
```

Have no idea how to fix it, pls help someone
`Magick++-config` code:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Configure options script for re-calling Magick+ compilation options
# required to use the Magick++ library.
#
#

prefix=/usr/local
exec_prefix=${prefix}

usage='Usage: Magick++-config [--cppflags] [--cxxflags] [--exec-prefix] [--ldflags] [--libs] [--prefix] [--version]

 For example, "magick.cpp" may be compiled to produce "magick" as follows:

  "c++ -o magick magick.cpp `Magick++-config --cppflags --cxxflags --ldflags --libs`"'

if test $# -eq 0; then
      echo "${usage}" 1>&2
      exit 1
fi

while test $# -gt 0; do
  case "$1" in
    -*=*) optarg=`echo "$1" | sed 's/[-_a-zA-Z0-9]*=//'` ;;
    *) optarg= ;;
  esac
  case $1 in
    --prefix=*)
      prefix=$optarg
      ;;
    --prefix)
      echo $prefix
      ;;
    --exec-prefix=*)
      exec_prefix=$optarg
      ;;
    --exec-prefix)
      echo $exec_prefix
      ;;
    --version)
      echo '7.1.1 Q16 HDRI'
      ;;
    --cflags)
       --cflags Magick++-7.Q16HDRI
      ;;
    --cxxflags)
       --cflags Magick++-7.Q16HDRI
      ;;
    --cppflags)
       --cflags Magick++-7.Q16HDRI
      ;;
    --ldflags)
       --libs Magick++-7.Q16HDRI
      ;;
    --libs)
       --libs Magick++-7.Q16HDRI
      ;;
    *)
      echo "${usage}" 1>&2
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
  shift
done
```

Comment: `sudo cp -r * ../` ... no, why? You've now littered `/usr/inlude` with all the `ImageMagick-7` headers. You should use `#include <ImageMagick-7/header.h>` in your code, not change where it's installed.

Comment: Or if you are really lazy at typing, add `-isystem /usr/local/include/ImageMagick-7/` to your compile flags. `sudo cp -r * ../` is definitely not the correct approach.

Comment: maridj: If you do `/bin/sh --version`, what does it say? The `/usr/local/bin/Magick++-config` script is pretty short, so can you copy that into the question too? I'm not sure it's 100%  `/bin/sh`-safe so you could try to change the shebang to `#!/bin/bash` to see if that helps.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo: I did it because all lib files have imports like "path/to/file" instead of "ImageMagick-7/path/to/file". I didn't know about `-isystem`, I will keep that in mind for the future. 
`/bin/sh --version` gives me `/bin/sh: 0: Illegal option --` output. But `/bin/bash --version` gives `GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>`. I also have updated post by adding magick++-config code

Comment: In general, you never touch things managed by your system's package manager, unless those are some config files. At this point you should uninstall the imagemagick package, carefully scrub `/usr/include`, then reinstall it again.

Comment: @maridj I see that you are missing `pkg-config`. When `ImageMagick` is being built, it will instrument the `Magick++-config` script so that the lines in the switch-cases contains the full path to it, like this: `/usr/bin/pkg-config --cflags Magick++-7.Q16HDRI` but your lines read `--cflags Magick++-7.Q16HDRI` which means that `pkg-config` is missing. To fix this, you need to first install `pkg-config` and then re`./configure`, rebuild and reinstall `ImageMagick`.

Comment: Also, you may want to download the latest version of ImageMagick from github. I got a [pull request](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/pull/7008) through a few hours ago that fixes another issue in `Magick++-config`. It simply does not work unless the `pkg-config` files (`.pc`) are installed in a directory searched by default, but after my PR, it will work.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Maybe `pkgconfig` should be in the **homebrew** prerequisites on macOS anyway? I know you do not get PNG support on Debian/Ubuntu either if `pkgconfig` isn't installed as **ImageMagick** fails to find PNG support without it.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Yes, it seems like a bad idea to instrument the `Magick++-config` script when the `PKG_CONFIG` variable they use to instrument it is unset or blank :-) I think `./configure` should detect and refuse - or perhaps provide an option to build and install without `Magick++-config` support if wanted, and then of course not create a `Magick++-config` script at all.

Comment: @maridj ... and you may want to download it again in a few hours when [this](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/pull/7013) has been merged which fixes a bug that my fix introduced :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i fix my issue. Firstly, I'm very thankful to @Ted Lyngmo for help. So in my case solution was:

1. remove  imagemagick (but not completely to be honest)
2. complete instructions from https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/main/Install-unix.txt

Despite of errors during `cmake check` it works fine

Answer (score 1):

Try defining the missing constants:

```
c++ -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=1 ...
```

These are pretty reasonable defaults for most users.

---

If you want to be able to:

- process 32-bit float values (e.g. TIFF/PFM/FITS) files, or
- do FFTs, or
- high accuracy convolutions/filtering, or
- gradients without banding, or
- you want the most compatible, flexible, capable, general-purpose **ImageMagick** possible,

use 32 and 1 instead.

---

If you only ever want to process JPEGs and 8-bit PNGs (bear in mind some PNGs have 16-bit samples), and want to maximise speed and minimise RAM usage, use 8 and 0.

---

If you want to check what values you used when you compiled **ImageMagick**, run `identify -version` and look at the parameter `Q` in the first line:

```
identify -version
Version: ImageMagick 7.1.0-48 beta Q16-HDRI x86-64 ...
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I still receive an error, but now it is a linking problem https://pastebin.com/wqDHkqEx (I am really sorry, but I don't know how to paste this long output to the comment in another way)

Comment: Have you installed `pkgconfig` - it may be `pkg-config`, not sure.